# Changing value of variable inside argument in kotlin

Tags: kotlin, parameter-passing

In Java you can do the following:

```
boolean a = true;
if(a = false) {
   //////
}
```

And a will be set to false and be used after that as argument. But in kotlin, I couldn't find a way to do that, except for:

```
var a = true
a = false
if(a) {

}
```

Is there any better way?

Comment: The best way IMO is just to separate the assignment from the `if`, as you did. It's very clear, and I believe Kotlin was designed intentionally to prevent this use of assignment as expressions.

Comment: why would you want to do that? The body of the `if` will never be executed. and this code is super confusing anyway. Kotlin specifically forbids assignments to be used anywhere else.

Answer (score 8):

You can do this inline in a slightly different order - by writing the value to be assigned (`false`) first, and using the [`also`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/scope-functions.html#also) scope function to assign it:

```
var a = true
if(false.also { a = it }) {

}
```

However, I would not recommend you to do this in either Java or Kotlin, as this is not very readable. There is nothing bad about writing the assignment as a separate statement.